# Joining 4 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, left-join, union

Need help on this question.

- Table A : SR#, activity, status, date/time (E.g:100, Create, open, 2019-01-01)
- Table B : SR#, SO#, activity, status, date/time (E.g: 100, A100, Update, in-progress, 2019-01-02)
- Table C : SO#, activity, status, date/time (E.g: A100, Delete, Cancelled, 2019-01-03)
- Table D : SO#, activity, status, date/time( data may present or none)

SR# may have none(null) or multiple SO's so I need a final table of A, B, C and D which should contain

```
SR#, SO#, activity, status, date/time
100, A100, Create, open,2019-01-01
100, A100, Update, in-progress, 2019-01-02
100, A100, Delete, Cancelled, 2019-01-03
```

Note: Table B/C/D may or may not have data. Final table should be A, B, C and D.

I tried left join but it's not working. It's giving all the rows from all tables. I am looking for merging all the table columns based on SO#.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.*, B.*, C.*, D.*
FROM B 
LEFT JOIN A ON A.SR# = B.SR# 
LEFT JOIN C ON C.SO# = B.SO# 
LEFT JOIN D ON B.SO# = D.SO#
```

Output is returning all the rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: SO# is used as a primary key in table B and should be used as a secondary key for C and D. Left join will bring in all data from column C and D even if they dont exist in B because of the SR# key. I would evaluate the joins.

Comment: *"I tried left join but it's not working. It's giving all the rows from all tables"* you have no `WHERE` so o *suspect* this is to be expected. Sample data for those expected results might help us help you here.

Comment: Reconsider this database design as different tables should not have same named columns. Normalize by using one table to capture same metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `UNION` query across all `JOIN` pairs to *Table B*,  explicitly defining same columns in each `SELECT`:

```
SELECT B.[SR#], B.[SO#], A.[activity], A.[status], A.[date/time]
FROM B 
INNER JOIN A ON A.[SR#] = B.[SR#]

UNION

SELECT B.[SR#], B.[SO#], B.[activity], B.[status], B.[date/time]
FROM B 

UNION

SELECT B.[SR#], C.[SO#], C.[activity], C.[status], C.[date/time]
FROM B 
INNER JOIN C ON C.[SO#] = B.[SO#]

UNION

SELECT B.[SR#], D.[SO#], D.[activity], D.[status], D.[date/time]
FROM B 
INNER JOIN D ON D.[SO#] = B.[SO#]
```